# Bootstrap is not Displaying "Hero-Unit" Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create `Hero Unit` in my page, I have used the following code, but its not displaying hero unit. Kindly guide me what i am missing here.

I have included `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap-theme.min.css` .

```
 <div class="hero-unit">        
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                <h1>Skills Management System</h1>   
                <P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Find the Best Skills for any of your Project</P>
            </div>      
      </div>
```

Comment: Please read bootstrap documentation before posting your questions here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been replaced by `jumbotron` in [Bootstrap 3](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide). Also, make sure your `col..` is placed inside a `row`..

```
<div class="jumbotron">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
       <h1>Skills Management System</h1>   
       <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         Find the Best Skills for any of your Project</p>
     </div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/BGzdeYeguk

Comment: Thank you so much, This is working completely fine now..I want to draw a border-box around a div? How can i achieve this using bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Please verify your bootstrap version.
In bootstrap 3.0 hero-unit was replaced by "jumbotron"

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you inputed `bootstrap-theme.min.css` , so I think you are using `Bootstrap 3`.

But your code shows that you were using `Bootstrap 2` style.

So, just change the class 'hero-unit' to 'jumbotron' which was changed in `Boostrap 3`:

```
<div class="jumbotron">   
    <h1>Skills Management System</h1>
    <P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     Find the Best Skills for any of your Project</P>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'col-xs-..' would also imply Bootstrap 3.x is being used.